# The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method

Tags: spring-mvc, web, multipartform-data, multipart, thymeleaf

This is my html page

```
<form id="addsftpserver" name="addsftpserver" action="user-serverconfigurationSFTPSave" method="put"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This in spring conf xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
</bean>
```

Pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user-serverconfigurationSFTPSave", headers={"content-type=multipart/form-data"})
public String serverconfigurationSFTPSave(Model paramModel,@RequestParam(value = "privateKey", required = false) CommonsMultipartFile privateKey,<other params>,HttpServletRequest req) {}
```

But i am getting the following error:
The server refused the request because the request entity is in a format which is not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ();

Can any one point me my error

Answer (score 0):

If your form method is `PUT`, then you need to have a `@RequestMapping` that will map to the PUT. I think you need to add a `method = RequestMethod.PUT` to your `@RequestMapping`.

You may want to have the method (both in the form and `@RequestMapping`) be `POST` instead of `PUT`, depending on what you're trying to do.